# spanning over vectors, but this span has only 1 vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen a problem that asks the following:

Is the following a subspace:
$$H = \text{span}\left\{\left[\begin{array}{c}2\\0\\3\\4\end{array}\right]\right\}$$

I know the answer is yes it is a subspace, because a SPAN is a subspace by a corollary and I have even proved this.

BUT, I am having difficulty understanding how this one vector spans anything.
Is it supposed to span $\Bbb R^4$, I doubt it.

So if anybody has any ideas about how this span can span of some vector space, will really appreciate it.

[Also another way to phrase this problem is : Why is every span of a subset of a vector space a subspace?]

Palu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $R^3$ and cut your span to $span[2, 0, 3]$. Then we have the vector $2, 0, 3$, which spans multiples of $2, 0, 3$ so we have $n(2, 0, 3)$.

Now for $R^4$, do the same. As Betty mentioned it is one-dimensional.

If we had two lines, each with different one-dimensional span, we would end up getting a plane.

Answer (score 4):

H spans (and is a basis for)  a 1 dimensional subspace of R$^4$.